# iPhone JQuery: How to implement a Split view in iPad using Jquery Mobile + phone gap in iPhone

Tags: jquery, iphone, ipad, jquery-mobile, cordova

I had tried to implement a ***`split view`*** using the **`JQuery mobile Phone gap`**

*sample code in* **`index.html`**

```
    <head> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="inc/jquery.mobile.structure-1.0.1.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="inc/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="inc/resources/css/jquery.toastmessage.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="inc/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="inc/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="inc/phonegap-1.2.0.js"></script>
    </head> 

    <body> 

        <div data-role="page" data-theme="c">
            <div data-role="header">
                Mpbile Split View
            </div>   

            <div data-role="content">

                 <!--- Left side view------>
                <div class="left-content">
                    <h3>lef hand content</h3>
                    <ul data-role="listview">
                        <li>One</li>
                        <li>One</li>
                        <li>One</li>
                        <li>One</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <!--- Right side view------>
                <div class="right-content">
                    <h3>Right hand content</h3>
                    <ul data-role="listview">
                        <li>Two</li>
                        <li>Two</li>
                        <li>Two</li>
                        <li>Two</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </body> 
</html>
```

But it shows both view on same page one by one top to bottom as shown bellow

[image]

I need two tables as **`split view`** ***one in left side*** (***`root view`***) and **other in right side** (***`details view`***)

how is it possible using jQuery? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://jeromeetienne.github.com/jquery-mobile-960/ and split it with that grids.

If you know 960.gs or any other css grid framework it will be very easy for you. There is demo of usage at mentioned site.

Comment: This is a GitHub project that has not been updated in 3 years. The documentation seems to be very good and the main page serves as an example of how it works. On the other hand, it seems a little overkill if all you want is to divide iPod screen in half. Finally, there is a five month old comment, still unanswered, asking if it will be updated to support the latest versions of jQuery. I say "Nay!"

Answer (score 1):

Try using my [multiview plugin](https://github.com/frequent/multiview/tree/master/multiview%20JQM%201.1).

It allows 1/2/3 panels side-by-side plus popover panels in Jquery Mobile. I have not tried it with PhoneGap (just finishing for JQM 1.1), so if you give it a try, please let me know if it works (it should I guess).

Please use the 1.1 version and the JQM 1.1.multiview, which needs a few tweaks to get working.

I'm currently doing the new README and sample site. Should be up in a few days.

Comment: This is a GitHub project that has not been updated in 2 years, still does not have a README file nor any other documentation that I can see, and still no pointers to a sample site. I say "Nay!"

Comment: If you can afford the time to provide any of th above, feel free to fork, update and maintain, because I currently can't...

Answer (score 1):

Try simplesplitview

http://simplesplitview.sourceforge.net/

Its the best jquerymobile splitview and damn easy to implement